# Look for numbers that is supposed to exist, but doesn't

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a long list of numbers.
Is there any way I could display the numbers that doesn't exist? In this case it would be `2` and `4`

```
1
3
5
6
```

The list is in a text file. To clarify, I just have one single list and it goes like this

```
1
2
3
4
5 
6 
...
800
801
802
...
1000
```

It's not supposed to compare to another just count what numbers are missing, if 804  and 806 exist but not 805 then it should list 805.

Comment: What is the input, one file or two files?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Are both lists in separate files? In separate variables? Why don't you also want to see 7-12? Those are also missing.

Comment: The last one was just a short example of what is missing, i have 1000s of numbers. The first list is just what my list looks like

Comment: So why `2` should be in output? It is present in the first list.

Comment: When asking this type of question, you need to give an example of your input and the output you would like to get.

Comment: I did that, look at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'NR == 1 {n = $1; next}
     {while (++n < $1) print n}' list.txt
```

Comment: Great, it worked. Thats what i mean, thanks.

Comment: `awk '{ if ( ++n < $1 ) print n  ; n=$0 }' list.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seq` to construct the full list, then use `grep` to see what's missing:

```
#!/bin/bash

list=$1
from=$(head -n1 $list)
to=$(tail -n1 $list)
grep -vwf "$list" <(seq "$from" "$to")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

for y in open(sys.argv[1]):
    y = int(y)
    x += 1
    while x < y:
       print x
       x += 1
```